# XSLT 3.0 - Removing and Replacing nodes (with Saxon 9.7)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have an input XML like following (requirements are highlighted as comments):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Aggregated_Data>

    <References>
        <Reference>
            <Type>Company_Reference_ID</Type>
            <Value>Dest Company</Value>
        </Reference>
        <Reference>
            <Type>ABC_Reference_ID</Type>
            <Value>XYZ</Value>
        </Reference>
    </References>


    <wd:root xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
        <wd:Calculated_Field_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
            xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <wd:Calculated_Field_Reference_ID>Ref</wd:Calculated_Field_Reference_ID>
            <wd:Name>NameABC</wd:Name>
           
            <wd:Conditional_Expression_Calculated_Field_Data>
                <wd:Conditional_Expression_Calculated_Field_Condition_Data>
                    <wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                        <wd:Order>dd</wd:Order>
                        <wd:And_Or_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</wd:ID>
                        </wd:And_Or_Reference> 

                        <!-- Need to remove every wd:ID node except the last one (in this case last one is "<wd:ID wd:type="Company_Reference_ID">ABC</wd:ID>") and replace last one's value from the value from References node with the same type (In this case type = Company_Reference_ID) -->
                        <wd:Filter_Instances_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e50d309a6d8540e3b533219cfa2c330b</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Organization_Reference_ID">ABC</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Company_Reference_ID">ABC</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Filter_Instances_Reference>                        
                       
                    </wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                </wd:Conditional_Expression_Calculated_Field_Condition_Data>
            </wd:Conditional_Expression_Calculated_Field_Data>
        </wd:Calculated_Field_Data>
        
        <!-- Has multiple <wd:Calculated_Field_Data> nodes -->
    </wd:root>

</Aggregated_Data>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Aggregated_Data>

    <References>
        <Reference>
            <Type>Company_Reference_ID</Type>
            <Value>Dest Company</Value>
        </Reference>
        <Reference>
            <Type>ABC_Reference_ID</Type>
            <Value>XYZ</Value>
        </Reference>
    </References>


    <wd:root xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
        <wd:Calculated_Field_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
            xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <wd:Calculated_Field_Reference_ID>Ref</wd:Calculated_Field_Reference_ID>
            <wd:Name>NameABC</wd:Name>
           
            <wd:Conditional_Expression_Calculated_Field_Data>
                <wd:Conditional_Expression_Calculated_Field_Condition_Data>
                    <wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                        <wd:Order>dd</wd:Order>
                        <wd:And_Or_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</wd:ID>
                        </wd:And_Or_Reference> 

                        <!-- Notice that after removing all wd:ID nodes except last, the value of last node was replaced from the value from References node of its type -->
                        <wd:Filter_Instances_Reference>                                
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Company_Reference_ID">Dest Company</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Filter_Instances_Reference>                        
                       
                    </wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                </wd:Conditional_Expression_Calculated_Field_Condition_Data>
            </wd:Conditional_Expression_Calculated_Field_Data>
        </wd:Calculated_Field_Data>
        
        <!-- Has multiple <wd:Calculated_Field_Data> nodes -->
    </wd:root>

</Aggregated_Data>
```

To achieve this I have created the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="#all"/>
    
     <xsl:accumulator name="RefType" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="References/Reference/Type/text()"
            select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>


    <xsl:accumulator name="RefMap" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" streamable="yes"
        initial-value="map{}">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="References/Reference/Value/text()"
            select="map:put($value, accumulator-before('RefType'), normalize-space())"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    
    
   
    
    <!-- removes all nodes except last one -->
    <xsl:template match="wd:Filter_Instances_Reference/wd:ID[position() != last()]"/>
    
    <!-- replaces last node with value from accumulator from References node -->
    <xsl:template match="wd:Filter_Instances_Reference/wd:ID[position() = last()]">
        <xsl:variable name="type" select="./@wd:type"/>
        <wd:ID>
            <xsl:attribute name="wd:type"><xsl:value-of select="$type"/></xsl:attribute>
            
            <!-- Accumulator map value goes here -->
            <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('RefMap')($type)"/>
        </wd:ID>
    </xsl:template>
    
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**THE ISSUE:** Since my system uses lower version of Saxon (9.7 I believe), the above XSLT is throwing a streaming error:
*Template rule is declared streamable but it does not satisfy the streamability rules: **The match pattern is not motionless***

I suspect the reason for this is I have used predicates in the match expression to identify position of wd:ID nodes in both the templates. However, when I execute the same XSLT in a Saxon processor with higher version (10.6), I get the expected output, linked [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aB9NL5/1).

**I just wanted to know if there is any other way to achieve my requirement without using predicates to compare positions of the nodes or any other better way to achieve my requirement in lower XSLT 3.0 saxon environments. Any help is appreciated!**

Comment: Do you get that code to run with streaming and Saxon 10 EE? Or only without streaming? Also is the value of that `wd:type="Company_Reference_ID"` not usable in the predicate instead of the `position() = / != last()" checks?

Comment: Does the `wd:Filter_Instances_Reference` element only have those `wd:ID` elements? Or others as well? If there are only those `wd:ID` elements you could set up an accumulator to match and store the current `wd:ID`, then use a template matching `wd:Filter_Instances_Reference` doing a shallow copy, inside `xsl:apply-templates` and then you can read out the accumulator value and create a new `wd:ID` element and use the accumulator value it to lookup the new value.

Comment: Hi Martin, I haven't tried this on Saxon 10 EE as I don't have a tool that has that. Regarding the predicate, no we cannot use `wd:type="Company_Reference_ID"` because these types are not pre-known. Hence my solution was based on ID positions. And Yes, the `wd:Filter_Instances_Reference` element only has `wd:ID` elements. I see you have provided a solution for this as an answer, I will try that and let you know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up an accumulator (assumes `xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday/bsvc"`, otherwise prefix the element names with `wd`)

```
  <xsl:accumulator name="id" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" stremable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Filter_Instances_Reference" select="map{}"/>
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Filter_Instances_Reference/ID/text()" select="map { ../@wd:type/string() : string() }"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
```

then use templates

```
  <xsl:template match="Filter_Instances_Reference">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <wd:ID wd:type="{accumulator-after('id') => map:keys()}">{accumulator-before('RefMap')(accumulator-after('id') => map:keys())}</wd:ID>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Filter_Instances_Reference/ID"/>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, although the solution is working, I am having troubles understanding fully how did the accumulator know that it needs to pick the "last" `wd:type` and its corresponding value from `wd:ID` nodes. I have few more similar requirements, so wanted to make sure I understand this. Appreciate your inputs!

Comment: @HarishM, the accumulator stores the currently processed `Filter_Instances_Reference/ID/text()` when such a node is processed. As the template for `Filter_Instances_References` does `<xsl:apply-templates/>` first, i.e. processes all its child nodes, and "then" reads out the `accumulator-after` value it has to be the value of the last `ID/text()` that was processed by the `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.